# Maximization of a concave function with contraints in the arguments

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum

I have been struggling on solving this problem. Suppose you have a function f(x, y) that is concave in x and y. I want to find (x, y) that maximize f(x, y) with x `\in` [0, 1] and y `\in` [0, 1].

Assume I have the following function:

```
f[x_, y_, t1_, p_, k_] := t1 *(y + p (x - y)) - k*((y + p (x - y - 1))^2 + (p (1 - x) - y (1 - p))^2)
```

The variables have the following contraints: 0 <= p <= 1, k >= 0, t1 > 0, 0 <= x <= 1 and 0 <= y <= 1.
To solve this, I compute the FOC with respect to x and y:

```
D[f[x, y, t1, p, k], x] and D[f[x, y, t1, p, k], y]
```

which gives:

```
{{x -> (4 k p + t1 - 4 k y + 4 k p y)/(4 k p)}} and {{y -> (-4 k p - t1 + 4 k p x)/(4 k (-1 + p))}}
```

Then solving the system I get x = x... How should I proceed then? My intuition tells me that x = 1 and y should be decreasing in k.

Sorry if the question is very basic and thanks in advance.

Comment: show your try code please ! use in post box {} to insert code within

Comment: also clarify your question in neat manner; which are function, variables, constants with constrain !? Like p(x-y) function of x and y or just multiplication of variables !??

Comment: Thanks @Alrubaie. I tried to improve my answer.

Comment: Define `g[z_]:=-2*k*(z-p)^2+t1*z`, then your function is equal to `g[p*(x-y)+y]`. So all you have to do is maximize the function `g` of one variable.

Answer (score 6):

If I correctly understand the question, `Maximize` does the job in 13.1 on Windows 10:

```
Maximize[{t1*(y + p (x - y)) -   k*((y + p (x - y - 1))^2 + (p (1 - x) - y (1 - p))^2), 
0 <= x && x <= 1 && y >= 0 && y <= 1 && p >= 0 && p <= 1 && k >= 0 &&
t1 > 0}, {x, y}]
```

> `{Piecewise[{{-2*k - 2*k*p^2 + t1, t1 > 0 && p == 0 &&  Inequality[0, LessEqual, k, LessEqual, t1/4]},  {2*k - 2*k*p^2 + t1, t1 > 0 && p == 1 && k >= 0},  {-2*k + 4*k*p - 2*k*p^2 + t1,  (t1 > 0 && Inequality[0, Less, p, Less, 1/2] &&  Inequality[0, LessEqual, k, Less, -(t1/(-4 + 4*p))]) ||  (t1 > 0 && Inequality[1/2, LessEqual, p, Less, 1] &&  Inequality[0, LessEqual, k, Less, -(t1/(-4 + 4*p))])},  {(-16*k^2*p^2 + t1^2)/(8*k), t1 > 0 && p == 0 && k > t1/4},  {(8*k*p*t1 + t1^2)/(8*k),  (t1 > 0 && Inequality[0, Less, p, Less, 1/2] &&  k == -(t1/(-4 + 4*p))) || (t1 > 0 && Inequality[0, Less,  p, Less, 1/2] && k >= -(t1/(-4 + 8*p))) ||  (t1 > 0 && Inequality[0, Less, p, Less, 1/2] &&  Inequality[-(t1/(-4 + 4*p)), Less, k, Less,  -(t1/(-4 + 8*p))]) || (t1 > 0 && Inequality[1/2,  LessEqual, p, Less, 1] && k == -(t1/(-4 + 4*p))) ||  (t1 > 0 && Inequality[1/2, LessEqual, p, Less, 1] &&  k > -(t1/(-4 + 4*p)))}}, -Infinity],  {x -> Piecewise[{{1/2, (t1 > 0 && p == 0 && k > t1/4) ||  (t1 > 0 && p == 0 && Inequality[0, LessEqual, k,  LessEqual, t1/4]) || (t1 > 0 && Inequality[0, Less, p,  Less, 1/2] && k >= -(t1/(-4 + 8*p)))},  {1, (t1 > 0 && p == 1 && k >= 0) || (t1 > 0 &&  Inequality[0, Less, p, Less, 1/2] &&  k == -(t1/(-4 + 4*p))) || (t1 > 0 &&  Inequality[0, Less, p, Less, 1/2] &&  Inequality[0, LessEqual, k, Less, -(t1/(-4 + 4*p))]) ||  (t1 > 0 && Inequality[1/2, LessEqual, p, Less, 1] &&  k == -(t1/(-4 + 4*p))) || (t1 > 0 && Inequality[1/2,  LessEqual, p, Less, 1] && Inequality[0, LessEqual, k,  Less, -(t1/(-4 + 4*p))])},  {(-4*k + 12*k*p + t1)/(8*k*p),  (t1 > 0 && Inequality[0, Less, p, Less, 1/2] &&  Inequality[-(t1/(-4 + 4*p)), Less, k, Less,  -(t1/(-4 + 8*p))]) || (t1 > 0 && Inequality[1/2,  LessEqual, p, Less, 1] && k > -(t1/(-4 + 4*p)))}},  Indeterminate],  y -> Piecewise[{{1/2, t1 > 0 && p == 1 && k >= 0},  {1, (t1 > 0 && p == 0 && Inequality[0, LessEqual, k,  LessEqual, t1/4]) || (t1 > 0 && Inequality[0, Less, p,  Less, 1/2] && k == -(t1/(-4 + 4*p))) ||  (t1 > 0 && Inequality[0, Less, p, Less, 1/2] &&  Inequality[0, LessEqual, k, Less, -(t1/(-4 + 4*p))]) ||  (t1 > 0 && Inequality[1/2, LessEqual, p, Less, 1] &&  k == -(t1/(-4 + 4*p))) || (t1 > 0 && Inequality[1/2,  LessEqual, p, Less, 1] && Inequality[0, LessEqual, k,  Less, -(t1/(-4 + 4*p))])},  {(-2*k*p - t1)/(4*k*(-1 + p)), t1 > 0 &&  Inequality[0, Less, p, Less, 1/2] &&  k >= -(t1/(-4 + 8*p))}, {(-4*k + 4*k*p - t1)/ (8*k*(-1 + p)), (t1 > 0 && Inequality[0, Less, p, Less,  1/2] && Inequality[-(t1/(-4 + 4*p)), Less, k, Less,  -(t1/(-4 + 8*p))]) || (t1 > 0 && Inequality[1/2,  LessEqual, p, Less, 1] && k > -(t1/(-4 + 4*p)))},  {t1/(4*k), t1 > 0 && p == 0 && k > t1/4}}, Indeterminate]}}`

Addition.

```
 FullSimplify[%,Assumptions->p >= 0 && p <= 1 && k >= 0 && t1 > 0]
```

> `{Piecewise[{{-2*k + t1, p == 0 && 4*k <= t1}, {-2*k*(-1 + p)^2 + t1, p >= 1 || (p > 0 && 4*k*p + t1 > 4*k)},  {t1^2/(8*k), p == 0 && 4*k > t1}}, (t1*(8*k*p + t1))/(8*k)],  {x -> Piecewise[{{1/2, p <= 0 || 8*k*p + t1 <= 4*k},  {1, p >= 1 || (p > 0 && (4*k*p + t1 == 4*k || 4*k + t1/(-1 + p) <= 0))}, {(4*k*(-1 + 3*p) + t1)/(8*k*p),  k + t1/(-4 + 4*p) > 0 && ((p > 0 && k + t1/(-4 + 8*p) < 0) || 2*p >= 1)}}, Indeterminate],  y -> Piecewise[{{1/2, p == 1}, {1, (p == 0 && 4*k <= t1) || (p > 0 && p < 1 && 4*k*p + t1 >= 4*k)},  {(2*k*p + t1)/(4*k - 4*k*p), p > 0 && 8*k*p + t1 <= 4*k}, {1/2 + t1/(8*k - 8*k*p),  k + t1/(-4 + 4*p) > 0 && ((p > 0 && k + t1/(-4 + 8*p) < 0) || 2*p >= 1)}, {t1/(4*k), p == 0 && 4*k > t1}},  Indeterminate]}}`

Comment: The same constraints used in the `Maximize` can be used to `FullSimplify` the result

Comment: @BobHanlon: Thank you for your valuable comment.